OVS does not receives package even after redirecting it explicitly by a pfSense rule
I am trying to receive a NTP package with the help of netfilter queue which is actually destined for a device inside my local network (behind a Wifi-AP).
My understanding is that iptables should be able to grab the package at the Open vSwitch (which should be working on OSI layer 3, since it has its own ip address).
To achieve my goal I configured a pfSense firewall WAN (later also LAN) rule, so incoming ntp packages from any ip address destined to any ip address/ any port use the OVS as gateway.
I can see how the ntp packages are routed through my local network. Here are the according lines from tcpdump:
16:05:39.847140 enp33s0f2 P   IP 10.12.1.130.51872 > time2.google.com.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
16:05:39.847147 vnet1 Out IP 10.12.1.130.51872 > time2.google.com.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
16:05:39.847273 vnet0 P   IP pfsense.*****.local.32015 > time2.google.com.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
16:05:39.879695 vnet0 Out IP time2.google.com.ntp > pfsense.*****.local.32015: NTPv4, Server, length 48
16:05:39.879822 vnet1 P   IP time2.google.com.ntp > 10.12.1.130.51872: NTPv4, Server, length 48
16:05:39.879827 enp33s0f2 Out IP time2.google.com.ntp > 10.12.1.130.51872: NTPv4, Server, length 48

in other words:
ntp-request: enp33s0f (My Wifi-AP) → vnet1 (br_lan/ before firewall) → vnet0 (br_wan/ behind firewall)
ntp-response: the same, just backwards.
After "Waiting for NTP packets (Ctrl+C to stop)..." the console remains pretty quiet, so I assume that the package is never received by the python scrip. The iptables rules inside my python script are the following:
iptables -t raw PREROUTING --sport 123 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 98

I reckon that I did not configure the firewall correctly or my OSI layer understanding is not the best. Maybe even the OVS just forwards the package directly to the WiFi-Ap even it is configured as gateway.
I am using kubuntu as operating system. I've been able to retrieve packages coming from the device and were redirected by the pfSense firewall. Used a firewall rule for this - I just do not understand why it does not work the other way around. Also I am not sure what exactly would be right approach - configuring the firewall NATs or the firewall rules.
I would really appreciate any help since I tried everything I got to debug this. Thanks in advance.
